# How to build a network using peer connections of multiple peers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc, peer

I want to build a network among multiple peers using WebRTC datachannel.

What is the best topology to be used for efficient communication and video conferencing?

Now what am I doing?

If 10 peers are alive, I am creating 10 peer connections at each peer.

There are several issues I am facing with this approach.

*If a peer is connected that should send an offer to each existing peer and 
it should answer each peer offer. So there is the problem.*

Is there an alternative to do it?

What would I like to do?

I want to implement a mesh topology, that is, create on peer connection that can communicate to each other peer.

How could I do that?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem? Is hard to find one.