# Current State of Javascript WebRTC Libraries?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, webrtc

I want to know that which framework or library is best to use WebRTC. Here is a small and incomplete list of libraries/SDK out there. Any lib that I forgot, feel free to let me know:

**Libraries:**

- [simpleRTC](http://simplewebrtc.com)
- [RTCMultiConnection](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org)
- [crocodileRTC](https://www.crocodilertc.net)
- [lynckia/licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/) (This is more interesting for their
  server side, MCU)
- [holla](http://wearefractal.com/holla/) (used by twelephone)
- [peerjs](http://peerjs.com) (data channel)
- [rtc.io](http://rtc.io/)
- [webrtc.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) (no changes for
  almost a year)
- [webrtc-data.io](https://github.com/erbbysam/webrtc-data.io) (stripped down, data
  only version of webrtc.io)
- [talky.io](http://talky.io) (uses simpleRTC)
- [easyRTC](http://easyrtc.com) (priologic)
- [tawk](https://tawk.com) (uses easyRTC, priologic)
- [rtccopy](https://rtccopy.com) (uses webrtc-data.io)

**Tutorial/resource for implementing:**

- [WebRTC Experiments & Demos](http://www.webrtc-experiment.com)
- http://badassjs.com/post/43090030238/peerjs-a-peer-to-peer-networking-library-in-javascript

Has somebody done a compare of all the frameworks? It would help those who are new to WebRTC.

## Update

Having researched on WebRTC as a new technology, I could not find a more complete source than your experience. I decided to post this question in order to make a trigger that will compare the available sources.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depends what you need, you need more the video/audio sharing, the screen sharing, the data sharing ? Some are build for data with datachannel, other are build around video/audio mostly. It's an early age for WebRTC and so it's the same for librairies. Here a good link about webRTC javascript API framework http://webrtchacks.com/whats-in-a-webrtc-javascript-library/

Comment: Which is best is highly dependent on your goals. None of them are all encompassing or equal.

Comment: I think that simple-peer should be added to the list: https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That should get you started :-) If you were focussing your question, we could point you to a smaller list. That is is also by no mean exhaustive, but should have the usual suspects.

Recording / Serverless

- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) - [www](https://recordrtc.org/): RecordRTC

MCU/SFU

- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/lynckia/licode) - [www](http://lynckia.com/licode/): lynckia/licode
- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) - [www](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/): meetecho (janus)
- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server) - [www](http://www.kurento.org/): kurento
- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet) - [www](https://jitsi.org/): jitsi (meetme)
- **open source** - [src](https://github.com/medooze) - [www](http://medooze.com/) meedoze
- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup) - [www](https://mediasoup.org/): media soup
- **open source** - [git](https://github.com/pion) - [www](https://github.com/pion): Pion
- **[acquired](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/corporate-strategy-office/acquisitions/acano.html)** by cisco [www](https://www.acano.com/): acano
- **proprietary** - [docs](https://docs.pexip.com/) - [www](https://pexip.com/) pexip
- **proprietary** - [src](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openclovevideo/) - [www](https://ingage.ai/) <s>openClove</s> (*pivoted*)
- **proprietary** - [git](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples) - [www](https://tokbox.com/) tokbox (openbox)

Signaling

- holla (used by twelephone)
- openPeer (hookflash)

API / SDK

- twilio (audio only)
- requestec (product: saypage)
- plivo
- Tokbox
- QuickBlox
- openClove
- tropo (audio only)
- weemo
- voximplant (audio only?)
- Priologic (easyRTC, tawk.com, proPhone)
- Dialogic
- bistri
- Apidaze
- CafeX
- hookflash
- Apizee (apiRTC)
- &yet (simpleRTC)
- RTCMultiConnection (muazkhan, demo)
- crocodileRTC - the company has been bought/absorbed three times over. I don't know what is the status of this library, you might want to contact peter dunkley for update.
- peerjs (data channel)
- rtc.io
- webrtc.io (no changes for almost a year)
- webrtc-data.io (stripped down, data only version of webrtc.io)

Product

- webrtc-enterprise.com (uses SkywayJS)
- talky.io (uses simpleRTC)
- tawk (uses easyRTC)
- rtccopy (uses webrtc-data.io)
- twelephone

Tutorials

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/Peer-to-peer_communications_with_WebRTC
- https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab

Comment: I think that simple-peer should be added to the list: https://github.com/feross/simple-peer