# P2P video streaming on Android using WebRTC

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, twilio, tokbox

I'm looking for a WebRTC platform/API/SDK for P2P video streaming from an Android camera to another Android device running my app http://www.gotyapp.com. I've looked at Twilio, they don't support it. So far only Weemo and Tokbox potentially. Any recommendations?

Comment: there are quite a few out there. you might want to check [the answer to this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857637/current-state-of-javascript-webrtc-libraries/24879451#24879451

Answer (score 2):

Weemo provides a complete set of APIs and SDK for Android.
You can either use Webrtc in your Android Chrome browser or integrate the SDK in a native App.
Ask for an API key here http://www.weemo.com/get-started-video-platform/
And get technical documentation at docs.weemo.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm Megan from Twilio.

We now have [Programmable Video for Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-android).

To install the library and its dependencies into an existing project you can start with [these instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks#android-sdk) for your `build.gradle`.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
// The Twilio Conversations Library and its dependencies reside on jCenter
compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.9.0'
```

Comment: Does this require a paid Twilio account or is there a free tier of sorts?

Answer (score -1):

TokBox gives your audio/video on Android for P2P video streaming form Android-Android, as well as Android-iOS-web if you decide to expand in the future. We also lets you do multiparty and real-time video recording/storage if you want to check it out. You can see a live demo (including recording) on https://opentokrtc.com and try out opentokrtc on Android or iOS.

Get started here: https://tokbox.com/opentok/quick-start/