# Node.js module for communicating between 2 clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm looking for a Node.js module (or a suggestion/idea) so that my server can create/handle a 2-way communication between specific clients

In other words, I want to be able to transmit data coming from client X to client Y and vice versa.

I was looking into `socket.io` but it seems to work as a traditional web socket server that receives messages from all clients and then sends the same message to all clients. I might be wrong as I have no experience in this field.

In my case, I do want my server to be able to receive messages from different clients but I want the server to then forward each of those messages to a specific client instead.

e.g.

- forward msg coming from client X to client Y only (and vice versa)
- forward msg coming from client A to client B only (and vice versa)
- etc.

I have zero experience with web sockets (I'm not even sure whether web sockets is what I'm looking for) but I do have experience with basic Node.js servers.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Let me know if you have any follow-up questions of if my code is broken.

Comment: I will do Jason, I haven't had time to check it yet but I will leave a comment as soon as I implement your solution thanks, but it looks like it is what I'm looking for..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Node.js WebSocket server, since you're coding the server, you have complete control over who gets what messages. You can do something like this...

When a client makes a WebSocket connection to the server and you store their connection object in an array, you can treat their connection's index in the array as their ID. If you want, you can broadcast this ID (and their IP address) to all other clients at that point to let them know who has connected. Then when a client wants to send a message to another client or clients, have the client doing the messaging include the destination client(s) along with the message. Here's the relevant parts of the server:

```
var client_list = [];

ws_server.on('request', function(request) {
  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

  //let all other clients know that a new client has arrived
  //send the new client's ID and IP address
  for(var i = 0; i < client_list.length; i++) {
    client_list[i].send(JSON.stringify({
      type: "new client",
      data: {
        ID: client_list.length,
        IP: connection.remoteAddress
      }
    }));
  }

  //store the new connection
  client_list.push(connection);

  //let the new client know what their ID is
  connection.send(JSON.stringify({
    type: "assignment",
    data: {
      ID: client_list.length - 1
    }
  }));

  //when you receive a message from a client of type "relay",
  //send it to the intended targets
  connection.on("message", function(message) {
    var parsed_message = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
    if(parsed_message.type === "relay") {
      for(var i = 0; i < parsed_message.targets.length; i++) {
        client_list[parsed_message.targets[i]].send(parsed_message.data);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

An outgoing message from a client would look like this:

```
{
  type: "relay",
  targets: [1, 33, 7],
  data: {
    content: "Hey guy!",
    origin: my_id
  }
}
```

I didn't test that, so let me know if it gives you trouble.

Comment: As I understand it, and I'm relatively new to Node.js and totally new to scaling Node.js in production, one might have to have multiple Node.js server instances. How do you deal with sharing open web sockets across those server instances? Maybe I should push this into its own SO question... See also "Production apps, and apps running more than a single web dyno, require an architecture that accounts for shared state between the dynos" (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets).

Answer (score 1):

I am new to NodeJs too. Brief answer to your question

**Socket.io** is the way forward. You can isolate your client communication by connecting them on different ports.

client X to client Y only - **port 1234**

client A to client B only - **port 1256**

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Socket.io** will help you set up websockets between multiple clients and a server, so that you may synchronize data in real time between the connected instances. This is a **client-server communication**.

What I think you want is a **WebRTC** library, such as [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/). This one in particular sets up a **handshake** server using Node.js to bridge the connection between the two clients and let them communicate on their own from that point, for as long as the websocket lasts (i.e: a refresh will break the connection). This library can help you achieve **client-client** real time communication.

[This Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857637/current-state-of-javascript-webrtc-libraries) may help you further with a longer list of WebRTC libraries.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how much data OP wants to send.