# WebRTC few to many broadcast server, how to resolve high CPU usage?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I created a "few to many" WebRTC server using NodeJS package `wrtc`, that broadcasts a presenter (or a few presenters) to hundreds of viewers (ideally).

My implementation was inspired by this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMbdEnK8h3U, where the server simply adds audio and video tracks of the presenter `RTCPeerConnection` to all of the viewer's RTCPeerConnection instances.

The implementation actually works fine, except I'm experiencing high CPU consumption. Even just single presenter and viewer take up more than 30% CPU, with 2 presenters CPU consumption increases to about 90%.

I assume the underlying C++ WebRTC library must be decoding and re-encoding video streams (once the track gets passed from the presenter's RTCPeerConnection to the viewer's the decoding/encoding occurs). I can't think of anything else to cause the load.

Is there a way to pass the video stream without decoding/encoding, just passing already encoded data packets from the presenter peer connection to the viewer's connection?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is anything you can do with `wrtc`. A [fork](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc/issues/606#issuecomment-623506818) exists that makes it possible to not re-encode.

For node.js [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) is available and has everything you need!

You can see some other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857637/current-state-of-javascript-webrtc-libraries/24879451#24879451)

Comment: Thanks, got it working with mediasoup lib! Instead of 90% CPU it now hovers around 4% for 2 presenters :)