# Is WebRTC too privacy invasive to use for video chat without TURN servers?

Tags: webrtc, voip

I'd like to implement a simple video chat system for students to tutor each other. I'm a one man show, and would like a system I can run in a cost effective way starting with 10 users, and hopefully scale up as needed.

WebRTC seems like a great, low latency, and cheap option to build this feature. However, if clients are communicating, then they must know each other's public IP. Is this a significant privacy or security issue?

What is the worst case scenario of somebody getting my IP address? Wouldn't any malicious actor have to get through my ISP to get my specific location?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been running WebRTC services for the last 6 years. We found out very quickly that you can't run a production WebRTC service without TURN - users have Double NAT, CGNAT, or weird firewalls that prevent STUN from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you host it yourself, WebRTC can be extremely cost-effective.  I've been running the SFU at [galene.org](https://galene.org:8443) (disclaimer: I'm the main developer), which is used for multiple lectures with up to a hundred students.  Even though this is a full-fledged SFU (and not a mere TURN server), hosting amounts to just over €6/month.

If your tutoring sessions involve just two or three people, then peer-to-peer WebRTC might be enough, but even then a TURN server will be required, especially if some of your users are on university networks.  For larger groups, you will need to push your traffic through an SFU.

If you do peer-to-peer WebRTC, then any user can learn the IP of any user they are communicating with; this is most probably not an issue, since the IP addresses are most probably already being disclosed (e.g. in mail headers).  If you go though an SFU, then the IP addresses are not deliberately disclosed, but they might still leak; for example, the SFU implementation mentioned above ([Galene](https://galene.org)) discloses IP addresses when a user initiates a file transfer since file transfers happen directly between clients, in a peer-to-peer fashion.  (It may be possible to avoid this disclosure by setting the `iceTransportPolicy` field to `relay` in the [`PeerConnection` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection), but I haven't tested how effective it is.)

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC doesn't have to be P2P. You could run a SFU. Each user will upload their video to your server, and the server will distribute via WebRTC. Then the users will never know each others IPs.

I don't have any exact numbers, but it isn't expensive either. Your biggest expense will probably be bandwidth. Lots of Open Source SFUs exist, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857637/current-state-of-javascript-webrtc-libraries/24879451#24879451) is a good list to get started.

Comment: I checked out Twilio's STUN and TURN API pricing, and bandwidth seems pretty costly at $0.40 - $0.80 per gig. Tutoring sessions can have up to two 1080p streams and two 720p video streams, as well as voice streams. That’s around $2.50+ for an hour long tutoring session. Is this just considered cheap for video streaming?

Comment: It might be more cost effective to run your own TURN server? It is very easy. You could also look at Twilio competition like Subspace and Xirsys.